# Can you please explain when the zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant() and zonedDateTime.toInstant() give different outputs?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time

Can someone please state when these two types of ways to adjust a ZonedDateTime to UTC differ?? If possible provide some test event date times also.

```
String eventDate = "2016-11-28T10:56:28+11:00"; // my example date time
ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(eventDate.trim(), 
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX"));
// defaulting to UTC Zone 

//1st way
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant());

//2nd way
System.out.println(zonedDateTime.toInstant());
```

Comment: How do the two outputs differ? In my environment, they don't...

Comment: They can't differ, because both represents the same instant as requested (`withZoneSameInstant`). The dates differ but not the instants.

Comment: What's different in my environment is `System.out.println(zonedDateTime.withZoneSameLocal(ZoneId.of("UTC")));`. By the way, I think you are parsing a date time with an offset, not a zone. Consider using an `OffsetDateTime`, but that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @deHaar the outputs wont differ with the input date that i have used because of the above date being in ISO format.. my question was are these two ways any different for other date time inputs that might not necessarily have the same formats or timezone or offsets.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès Could u please elaborate more specifically towards the context of the question?

Comment: @VaishaliGupta An Instant is a point on the "universal" timeline. What  `withZoneSameInstant` did is (as the name suggest) to build the appropriate `Zoned` date with the **same** instant. So extracting the instant in both will always give the same result... Same instant : two different date/time in different zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my question was are these two ways any different for other date time inputs that might not necessarily have the same formats or timezone or offsets.

There cannot be any difference. You will always get the same instant from both ways.

The reason is: A `ZonedDateTime` always uniquely defines a point in time, an instant. After converting to another time zone using `withZoneSameInstant` the new `ZonedDateTime` will always define *the same* point in time, the same instant.

BTW deHaar is correct in the comment: Your string contains an offset from UTC, `+11:00`, and no time zone like for example `Asia/Shanghai`, so `OffsetDateTime` is a more appropriate class than `ZonedDateTime` for your purpose.